# prove quadratic polynomial has no real roots

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, proof-writing, quadratics, real-numbers

The problem asks me to prove that a polynomial $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ has no real roots for some $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$

I started by assuming that $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ has real roots and therefore the determinant $a^2-4b \geq 0$ and that $a \geq \pm 2 \sqrt{b}$ which imples that $b \geq 0$ which contradicts the fact that $b \in \Bbb{R}$ is this a correct way of doing this proof?

Comment: uhm, is $b$ very large or something?

Comment: the claim is false as currently stated

Comment: @JorgeFernández i dont understand?

Comment: How does $b\geq 0$ contradict that $b\in\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

You just have to show that the statement is true for some $a,b$.

Why dont' we set $a=0$, now can you choose a $b$ such that $x^2+b$ has no real root?

Remark about your attempt:

From $$a^2 \geq 4b,$$ when you take square root, it seems that you have assumed that $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$.

Comment: would my method still be valid?

Comment: From $a^2-4b \geq 0$, there is nothing wrong with $b$ being negative, in fact, if $b<0$, $a^2-4b \geq 0$ for sure.

Comment: so is it enough to say consider when $a=0$ and $b=2$ because then there exist real numbers $a,b$ such that $x^2+ax+b=0$?

Comment: you mean $x^2+ax+b \neq 0$ for such $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ for this particular choice of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example where a=2*sqrt(b). Then we have something that we can factor into (x+sqrt(b))^2, and letting this equal zero, we get a real root for x, -sqrt(b). I may have made a mistake in my understanding of the problem, but it doesn't seem to be a correctly worded problem.

Comment: Also, I apologize for the ugly format. I've yet to look at how to enter things digitally

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on how to typeset your mathematical expressions.